# Making RSA keys from a password in PHP

Tags: php, encryption, rsa

Similar to the question in the ["Making RSA keys from a password in python
"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20483504/making-rsa-keys-from-a-password-in-python) question, I want to to repeatedly create the same pair of RSA keys using a given password.

The question mentioned above has this code as the answer:

```
from Crypto.Protocol.KDF import PBKDF2
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

password = "swordfish"   # for testing
salt = "yourAppName"     # replace with random salt if you can store one

master_key = PBKDF2(password, salt, count=10000)  # bigger count = better

def my_rand(n):
    # kluge: use PBKDF2 with count=1 and incrementing salt as deterministic PRNG
    my_rand.counter += 1
    return PBKDF2(master_key, "my_rand:%d" % my_rand.counter, dkLen=n, count=1)

my_rand.counter = 0
RSA_key = RSA.generate(2048, randfunc=my_rand)
```

I tried to replicate this code in PHP like this:

```
$password = "swordfish";
$salt = "yourAppName";

$master_key = hash_pbkdf2("sha256", $password, $salt, 10, 256);

$counter = 0;
function my_rand($n) {
  $counter++;
  return hash_pbkdf2("sha256", $master_key, "my_rand:" . $counter, 10, 256);
}

$RSA_key = openssl_pkey_new(???);
```

But I now don't know how to replicate the RSA key generator using the custom random function as the PHP `openssl_pkey_new` function and the `phpseclib` both do not have an option to add a custom random function.

What do I have to do to repeatedly generate the same RSA key pair from a given password?

Comment: What purpose would it serve to *generate* a keypair based on *password*? Is it for learning purposes or out of curiosity? I'm asking because I'm genuinely interested in the use case.

Comment: The purpose I want want to do this is because I want to try to make an encrypted chat application using RSA. This chat application should allow users to log in using username + password, so keys would need to be generated from this but in a way that they can log in multiple times.

Comment: But the process of generating a keypair means you want a *new* key that wasn't used before, that's the whole point behind *generating* two huge prime numbers. What's the purpose of asymmetric key if you're using it as if it's a shared symmetric key? What you're doing is using a shared secret to compute an encryption key - and your idea is good but your execution is flawed. What you came across is known as Diffie-Hellman key exchange, but your process is bad. I suggest you google what I mentioned (Diffie-Hellman) and to rethink your process.

Comment: Reiterating on what you're after - deriving an encryption key from username and password is definitely wrong approach. If you're creating encrypted chat application, you should negotiate an encryption key between two parties via DH (Diffie-Hellman) and then both parties create the key without actually ever transmitting the key. That way you can create new keys every time you open a new connection between participants. Creating one and the same asymmetric key based on username or password is insecure - the keys should be unguessable and in your case - they aren't.

Comment: Sorry Mjh, but this is **not** structurally flawed, even if it does have the an enormous amount of [usage issues](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1662/1172) and [implementation issues](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/24517/1172). So yeah, it should not be used, but for other reasons than you state. If implemented I would use Elliptic Curve cryptography instead, but that replaces one can of worms with a can of worms with ingredients, basically.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes the idea is ok, generate a key of some sort based on certain input that only a single person knows. But *generating* an asymmetric key, be it a prime factorization or elliptic curve, is completely flawed and misuse of PKI.  It's not even generating it in true sense of the word, it's recreating it and the fact you can't encrypt arbitrary payload makes the execution flawed. We can debate this to no end, but that doesn't mean we'll help anyone. This is XY problem, I'm sure that adequate solution can be found if we can determine what the real problem is.

Comment: Huh? Why wouldn't you be able to use this for asymmetric cryptography? Why is this different from *storing* a private key and encrypting it? And why would you not be able to use this with hybrid crypto (as with any RSA key) and use it for arbitrary messages? Some people want to have the private key without storing it. This is a valid use case *even if it is rather impractical for the reasons stated above*, such as never being able to ever change the password.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes so what you're saying is that it's perfectly ok to use asymmetric key for message encryption even though you're aware that asymmetric key has a size limit to data it can encrypt, before you resort to chunking or figuring out that you can use asymmetric+symmetric encryption. I know you know what I'm talking about, let's not do the whole internet rite of passage dance. Idea is not feasible, generating the same key from constant payload is not generating a key, it's re-creating it and it's absolutely insecure and god knows what other dragons lurk in this particular implementation

Comment: errr, has [hostile dancing](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/sc2/topic/19739974447) been detected on this exchange?

Comment: Jack, you realise as well you look like you'll be using the same salt for each iteration, which will significantly weaken any generated key (en mass)

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: you should not generate a RSA key pair from a given password

---

It looks like both OpenSSL nor phpseclib have been created with this in mind. This is not surprising as there is much to be said [against the solution itself](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1662/1172). Furthermore, there are many implementation issues, [especially for RSA](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/24517/1172).

---

If you would still go ahead to implement this ill advised scheme, then you should look up a PHP implementation for the key generation *and then store that with your solution*. The reason for this is that otherwise the random number generation, prime finding or RSA key generation method may change internally (when you upgrade the library) and produce a different key pair. I would not use this solution on Java even though it *does* let you insert your own RNG to allow for *deterministic key pair generation*, which is the technical term of what you're trying to do.

There are other ways of having users keep their private key secure, such as *password based encryption* of the key. This requires storage of the encrypted key, but at least it is common practice and has much less reason to fail.

You'll need some kind of hybrid cryptography if you want to encrypt arbitrarily sized messages - just like you'd have to with any other kind of RSA key pair, really.

---

Note that the situation is slightly better for Elliptic Curve cryptography. You could combine PBKDF2 with SHA-256 to create a private key, and then derive the public key by performing point multiplication of base point G with that private key value. This is much less likely to fail. You could use ECIES to encrypt with Elliptic Curves, as EC does not have a way to directly encrypt messages *or* keys.

---

However, you'd still have the problem that you can never change the password, and that you have to use a constant salt to always generate the same private key and public keys. Because of this, I would still not recommend the scheme, as it allows offline, multi-target attacks to find the password, using the public key value or a ciphertext.

To be sure that the password cannot be found it needs to be *really* strong - so strong that you probably have to store it somewhere.